# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener or DispatcherServlet registered?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**ContextLoaderListener** and **DispatcherServlet** have been registered in **web.xml**, even after intializing getting the error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener or DispatcherServlet registered?
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:253)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:332)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Just use Spring Boot to manage the auto-configuration, it will make your life easy.

Comment: but the code is in spring mvc

Comment: I know, I read the stack trace, use spring boot.

Comment: @Subha #Aniket  make it as springboot application it will slove both of u problem

Comment: @AniketSahrawat This is not good advice IMHO. Despite the fact that the Spring organization itself advocates what you say, using Spring boot without having a solid background first in Spring results in a developer that doesn't know the basics of how the spring framework works. Consequently, error messages makes no sense for him/her as they are often related to the Spring MVC life cycle.

Comment: Add this may fix your issue <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy Do you have knowledge of machine code that is being executed behind Java? Deal with abstraction.

Comment: We do deal with abstractions but after learning the abstracted layers in the vast majority of cases due to [the Law of Leaky Abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/). You have chosen a straw man example where the abstraction is nearly air-tight and the knowledge of the abstracted layer is basically useless for most developers. This is not even close in case of Spring Boot.

Comment: @Subha Please provide a [minimum verifiable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see your web.xml to offer you the help you need here.

Comment: @harkeshkumar added that listener you mentioned even then getting the exception

Comment: can you please share code or some file so we can help you